# bunyan - File-rotation with stream type 'raw'

Tags: node.js, bunyan

Bunyan provides rotating log functionality if the stream is type "rotating-file". I want to customize the JSON output written to my logs. For example I want some of the default values that bunyan writes but not all. It appears that if I wish exclude/rename properties that are output by default I need to create a stream of type 'raw'. If I use a 'raw' stream does it then become necessary to manage my own log rotation?

Note: I am already using serializers. But serializers just add an additional property containing a customized object.

```
 var log = bunyan.createLogger({
    name: 'foo',
    streams: [{
        type: 'rotating-file',
        path: '/var/log/foo.log', /* I'd like to be able to control what is written here while still having logs rotate */
        period: '1d',   // daily rotation
        count: 3        // keep 3 back copies
    }]
});
```